# Auto Layout setFrameSize on control's frameForAlignmentRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

In WWDC 2012 Session 228 video "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout", it explains intrinsicContentSize as a better sizeToFit and proceed with this example:

```
NSRect alignmentRect = (NSRect){NSZeroPoint, [control intrinsicContentSize]};
[control setFrameSize: [control frameForAlignmentRect:alignmentRect].size];
```

What's the purpose of doing the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video starts that section with "`intrinsicContentSize` also works with springs-and-struts". So, the first thing to understand is that this part is about when you're **not** using auto layout.

That's good, because `-setFrameSize:` should not be used when you are using auto layout.

So, what they're saying is that you can more accurately determine a good frame for a control by starting with its `intrinsicContentSize` than with `sizeToFit`. For a number of controls, if you call `-sizeToFit`, they will make themselves larger than is strictly necessary to accommodate their content (e.g. the label or the titles of the menu items in a pop-up button's menu). They explain that they can't make `sizeToFit` work better because of binary compatibility concerns even though the OS X theme or artwork has changed.

`intrinsicContentSize` is a better tool for making a control the size it needs to be to fit its content, and no larger. This is true now and, since there are no binary compatibility concerns with `intrinsicContentSize`, will continue to be true even as the theme and artwork change.

However, the intrinsic size is for the alignment rect of the control. For a view, there's the frame and then the alignment rect. The frame has to be big enough to encompass all of the drawing that the view does, even stuff that extends outside what a person looking at it would think of as its primary shape or size. The alignment rect is the boundary against which the auto layout system should align views. For example, if a view has a glow, the glow has to be within the view's frame but should be outside of its alignment rect (since other views should not align to the limits of the glow).

They are going to have to convert the intrinsic content size from an alignment size to a frame size. However, the only mechanism for converting from alignment to frame deals with rectangles (`NSRect`s), not sizes (`NSSize`s). So, they construct a rectangle of the appropriate size, convert that, then examine the size of the resulting rectangle.

They create an `NSRect` with its origin arbitrarily at (0, 0) and with a size of the control's `intrinsicContentSize`. That's what `(NSRect){NSZeroPoint, [control intrinsicContentSize]}` is. That's using the [C "compound literal" syntax](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-02-18-compound-literals.html) to make the `NSRect`. Note that there's an assumption here that the control has intrinsic content size in both dimensions, horizontal and vertical. Not all controls do. Some use `NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric`/`UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric` in one or both dimensions and this technique won't work for those controls, at least not without some adjustments.

Then, they convert the rectangle from an alignment rect to a frame rect. They have to ask the control to do this conversion. For some controls, the alignment rect and the frame may be equal; for others, there may be significant differences. Only the implementation of that control knows how its alignment rect and its frame should relate. So, you have to ask the control to do the conversion for you. That's what `[control frameForAlignmentRect:alignmentRect]` gives you.

Now you have a frame rect. The origin is basically arbitrary, since you started with `NSZeroPoint`. You don't want to `control.frame = <the computed frame>`. That would move the control to the arbitrary origin and you don't want to do that. You just want to set the control's size, leaving its origin alone. So, you extract the size from the computed frame rect. That's what the `.size` access is doing in `[control frameForAlignmentRect:alignmentRect].size`.

Finally, now that you have a new size for the control, you set it on the control. That is, you pass it to the `-setFrameSize:` method on the control. Now the control is as big as needed to fit its content but not bigger.